# calculator on actionscript 3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

This is the simplified version of my question.

There are

- movieclip1
- movieClip2
- movieClipadd
- TextA
- TextB
- Text C
- Text answer

  `Touching movieclip1 should change TextA to 1 (the content should be 1)
  Touching movieclip2 should change TextC to 2 (the content should be 2)`

  `Touching movieclipadd should change TextB to + (the content should be +)`

Then automatical Textanswer should give the answer. that is `3(1+2=3)`

This is for mobile and I know to use ontouchbegin and ontouchend.

Comment: what is your question exactly? are you hoping to have someone write the code for you? if so you are in the wrong place. tell us what you have tried and someone can perhaps help.

Comment: @arunkumar sorry this is my first time on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to accomplish what you want to do, one way would be to have a method for each operation type that you plan to have your calculator support, then you can just have a switch statement that calls the appropriate method, something like this (I got lazy and just did the operation inline, if it were more complicated would probably want methods):

```
switch(textB.text)
{
    case '+': textAnswer.text = parseInt(textA.text)+parseInt(textC.text);
        break;
    case '-': textAnswer.text = parseInt(textA.text)-parseInt(textC.text);
        break;
    //etc.
    default: throw new Error('unhandled operator');
}
```

assuming that you are going to use your knowledge of the touch handlers to populate the text boxes.

While I sort of agree with arunkumar due to the lack of code provided it's a simple enough problem with enough easy solutions to provide one.  But note that on SO it is standard that you provide your current work and as much background information as is relevant.